# Python: how to paste a list into another list

Tags: python, list

Help me please with this problem:
I have a list containing numbers and lists kind of:

```
list = [1,2,[3,4,5],6,7,[8,9]]
```

What I want to get is a list of just numbers (mergin included lists in parent list):
Example:

```
new_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: @msw: Look at OP's title. It's hard to search for things when you don't know the right words.

Comment: I saw big signature saying "marked as duplicate" what is the point of repeating that in comments? I just didn't know that it's called 'flatten'. Not knowing is not a crime. Everyone makes mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion and [`collections.Iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes):

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> def flat(lst):
...     for parent in lst:
...         if not isinstance(parent, Iterable):
...             yield parent
...         else:
...             for child in flat(parent):
...                 yield child
...
>>> list(flat(t))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Just remember to not name lists after their own type :).

Comment: `compiler.ast.flatten` is just a recursive function (that uses `type(foo) is list`), so your second solution is much better.

Comment: @Blender Eh, it is neater ;). But yea, I might as well remove it because it is deprecated

Comment: `if not isinstance(i, Iterable):`
instead of "i" you probably meant "parent"

Comment: @Haidro And thnx for solution

Answer (score 2):

I personally use this method :

This is a functional version of recursive flatten which handles both tuples and lists, and lets you throw in any mix of positional arguments. Returns a generator which produces the entire sequence in order, arg by arg:

```
flatten = lambda *n: (e for a in n
    for e in (flatten(*a) if isinstance(a, (tuple, list)) else (a,)))
```

Usage:

```
l1 = ['a', ['b', ('c', 'd')]]
l2 = [0, 1, (2, 3), [[4, 5, (6, 7, (8,), [9]), 10]], (11,)]
print list(flatten(l1, -2, -1, l2))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

This works fine with both python 3.x and python 2.x

Here is a regex solution for the same ..

```
 import re

 def Flatten(TheList):
   a = str(TheList)
   b,crap = re.subn(r'[\[,\]]', ' ', a)
   c = b.split()
   d = [int(x) for x in c]

   return(d)
```

Comment: -1 Couldn't you just have a regular function? Why stuck a long line into a lambda and name it to a variable right after it. That is not the purpose of the `lambda` keyword is what I'm saying. 'anonymous function'

Comment: -1. What if `L = [1, {2, 3}, 4, (5, 6, [7, 8], 9), {10, 11, 12, 13}]`?

Comment: @Haidro : The question demanded only for square brackets though..

Comment: @alexpinho98 :  I think using this makes it neater and according to zen of python .. `Beautiful is better than ugly.` Anyways to make it clearer about the use of `lambda` you should better see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why).Yes, regex is no doubt a better opinion ... Anyways edited the answer

Comment: @TusharMakkar IMHO I think the accepted answer's code is much more readable, pretty and easier to explain than the `lambda` version. `lambda` has it's uses and I've used it for many things like very short 'algebraic' functions and for functions like ´map´ and ´filter´, but i think that in this case ´lambda´ is not the right way. A good rule of thumb might be: 'if the statement is longer than some arbitrary amount(say 80) of characters and it involves recursion: use a normal function, else: use ´lambda´.

Comment: @alexpinho98 completely agree with you. Wanted to make a comment but you read my mind :)